# DNS-RPZ use for nonexistent addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone

I'm trying to find a scheme where I can use a generic UI app to automatically access some local IoT devices I'm making, no matter the domain in which they are installed.

Yes, I know IoT is just an IDIoT without his ID. And, yes, these devices are really, really dumb. But go with me here.

During installation, each device gets configured with a Device Number and a Static IP address. The Device Number is used to create the hostname of the form "devNN", where "NN" ranges from "00" to "99".

To keep the UI generic and simple for Users (no configuration or setup or anything), I'd like to map the local devices into my own domain.  That is, instead of a local address like "dev00.some.local.domain.com", I'd like the address to be within my own domain, e.g. "dev00.idiot.me".

I'm thinking I can use DNS-RPZ on the local DNS to accomplish this.

Thoughts?  Is there a better way to accomplish the same goal?

Thanks!

Comment: You should locate your devices with IPv6 multicast, if they are on the same link. There is no need for any sort of DNS hackery.

Comment: Unfortunately, these are really dumb devices, locked-in to IPv4.  They're former serial devices upgraded with a minimal wired Ethernet capability and barely enough smarts to host a REST API (old serial data format moved to JSON).  They need all the help they can get.

Comment: "Is there a better way to accomplish the same goal?" your goal does not seem clear enough for me. RPZ is a feature that is akin to a "DNS firewall" it allows to change DNS replies. The use case you present (using shorter names) just look like using a `search` or `domain` configuration item in `resolv.conf` or equivalent on the system that needs to do DNS queries.